# How do Advaitans respond to Hegel's Absolute Idealism?

Tags: hegel, idealism, german-philosophy, hinduism

I have read quite a bit of Hindu philosophy, particularly that of the Advaitan school, and I'm trying to improve my understanding of German Idealism.

My understanding of Hegel's Absolute is that it is a constantly evolving principle, not a static one as found in Advaita, in which any perceived concept of change is only a change of appearance. How would an Advaitan disprove that the Absolute or Brahman is not changing or evolving but in fact an unchanging reality?

Or is there no contradiction between Hegelianism metaphysics and Vedanta?